# Github: looking for a smart Git setup with shared files

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to Github and would like some advice how to arrange my workflow.

We have a small web application that we run on Mac Mini's using XAMPP. We have several Mac Mini's throughout the country and I was looking for a good way to manage the software and update it, because I was getting really frustrated with all the different versions.

The thing is that some files of the software are shared, but some files are specific for each client/Mac Mini. I'm looking for a easy setup so I have to change the common files only once and still have specific files (like templates) for each client.
The current situation is this:

- I have 1 software folder in my htdocs directory
- This folder has both specific and both common files in the root, like this:

  - sharedfolder
  - shared.html
  - specific.html
  - specificfolder
  - mediafolder (which I will ignore and not put on git)

I'm looking for the best way to manage this. I did some research on this topic, but I hope someone can advice me for this specific situation. I feel I have the following options:

1. Put everything in 1 repo but with the specific files in separate branches (do I have to push the changes to the common files to each client branche after a update?)
2. Use 2 repo's (and use .gitignore the separate the common files from the specific files). 1 with the common files and 1 with the client specific files (in separate branches). My early research told me that this isn't possible because everything is in my root and not a specific directory
3. Use git-subtree
4. Use git-submodules
5. Use gitslave
6. Anything else?

Ideal I'm looking for a solution that can be managed with a OSX Git GUI.

About my workflow. I hope that I can make all the changes to the code directly from my software folder in htdocs. If I only make changes to the common files I want to commit this to the common repo of course. If I make changes to a specific file I want to first connect to the right branche or repo and then update this.
I'm sorry for the incorrect terminology, but I hope it is still clear enough.

Would be very nice if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only solution that would work inside git is option 1 (branches).

The others all will not work if the files to be treated differently are all in one folder.

> do I have to push the changes to the common files to each client
>   branche after a update?

Yes, you do. Actually, you'd need to first merge your changes into the client branches (to be precise, into your local copy of the client branches), then push out all the client branches. 
That should work, though it may be a bit awkward. You could mitigate this by automating with some scripting.

---

If you can put the customized files into subfolders, then yes, you could use git-submodule, git-subtree or similar. However, I don't think that would work well in your case. git-submodule et al. are meant for situations where you want to keep things in *different repositories*. This means that the two parts (repositories) can be cloned independently, versioned independently, tagged & branched independently etc.

However, as far as I understand this is not what you want. The customized templates are all part of the software product, and will evolve along with the rest of the system. So having them in separate repos will only cause trouble (e.g. if you branch, you would need to branch each submodule separately - and, even worse, merge each submodule separately).

You just want to maintain different "versions" of some files, and this is just what branches are for.

---

However, you should consider a different approach, namely **performing the system-specific customizations at run-time**.

How to do this depends on the specifics, but as an idea, you could have a table of system-specific things. Then you detect your host system on startup (get hostname or similar), and apply the customizations.

This avoids all the problems with multiple branches, synchronizing them, testing them all and making sure to deploy the right one. Also, maybe even more important, you get to work on one codebase, and you can exploit similarities between the systems. Finally, you can switch individual parts of the customization on and off at runtime, which greatly simplifies debugging problems related to the customizations.

In my experience, this is a simpler and more robust approach than deploying files, maybe even different code on different systems. I have used this idea on several projects myself and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 

Would I expand my options if I place either all the common files OR all the specific files in a subdirectory in the htdocs folder? This should also be doable in the current situation.

I think I understand the option 1 repo with different branches. This could work.

Comment: I don't think I can follow your second option, I'm sorry to say. I'll try to explain my understanding of this. The specific files are mostly templates which hold specific coordinates for text and stuff like that. Now I'm thinking of making separate templates for all my clients. Are you meaning that I should make 1 template for all the clients and then apply the correct coordinates for that system by reading the hostname of the Mac Mini?

Comment: @user1737794: As I wrote, the details depend on the customizations. In your case, you could include the templates for all customers in each install, each marked with the customer they belong to. Then have a single setting "customerName" which switches to the right customer. Or if some customers use the same template, have "customerGroups" or "customerTypes". Or, if the templates are mostly the same, have conditional sections inside the templates (if your templating system suppots this). It's hard to be more specific without knowing the details, but I hope you get my idea.

Comment: @user1737794: About "moving files to subdirs": Yes, then technically you could use git submodule or similar. However, I don't think that would work well for your cases. I updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Great. I think I understand it all. I'll look into conditional sections in my templates. Thanks for your time and attention!